# How to define a query joining tables in two different databases

Tags: sqlyog

I know how to write SQL to join tables in two databases but is there a way to do this in SQLyog.

This type of query gives a permissions error in that application.

```
SELECT 
   DB1.table1.col1, 
   DB2.table2.col2
FROM DB1.table1 
JOIN DB2.table2
ON DB1.table1.commoncol1 = DB2.table2.commoncol2
```

**Additional info**

If I have open the tab for one database and run a query for another database (also open in its own tab)
ie

SELECT * FROM spixxxxxxx@51.195.123.67.databasename.tablename

where
`spixxxxxxx@51.195.123.67` is the connection

`databasename` is the database name

`tablename` is the table name

then I get the error

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@51.195.123.67.databasename.tablename' at line 1
```

Back ticks don't help and I get the same problem if I leave out the connection altogether (as I would expect)

Comment: you need to have the necessary permissions to access the tables in both databases. If you are getting a permissions error when running the query, it may be due to insufficient privileges on one of the databases or tables.

Comment: I have both databases (on different servers) already open in different tabs. I have full admin rights to both of my databases.

Answer (score 0):

do you think is that something do with running the application in sudo mode , so the problem of perimission would take place

Comment: I don't think sudo mode comes into it in this instance. As I commented to Sachin, I already have both databases open in separate connection tabs and can perform any operation I like on each one. I just don't seem to be able to join them.